# JS Form Validation

Tags: javascript

```
<html> 
<head> 
<title>Coupon test code</title> 
<style>
#error{
color: red;
font-weight: bold;
}
</style>
</head> 

<body> 
    <form name="couponField" action=""> 
        <span id="error"></span>
        Coupon code: 
        <input type="coupon" id="coupon" name="coupon"> 
        <input type="button" id="submit" value="Apply Coupon Code"> 
    </form> 

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$('#submit').click(function(){
    if($('#coupon').val() == 'PROMO CODE'){
        $('#error').text('correct code!');
    }else{
        $('#error').text('wrong code!');
    }

});
</script>

</body> 
</html>
```

The above code does the following:
1. Validate if the coupon code entered is exactly equal to 'PROMO CODE'
2. Validate if the field is empty.

What we are trying to do:
1. Keep the validation for 'PROMO CODE' intact.
2. Remove the validation for the empty field.

This is a part of an order form wherein we want the users to enter the promo code. But since all the users may not have the promo code we want to give the users the option to leave the field empty. The current validation is making this field a 'required' field.

Any suggestions are much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Your promo code is in the client side source… so all users have it.

Comment: You should never do validation on the client side.

Comment: Quentin and Joseph the Dreamer - Thanks for the tip. But will still like to know how to do the validation.

Comment: Here's a hint... your current code tests for one thing: whether or not the value equals the promo code.  It uses an if/else to assume that the code is _wrong_ if it doesn't match the code.  You will want to use an _else if_ to first check _IF_ it's empty, _ELSE IF_ it mathes the code, _ELSE_ assume the code is incorrect.  As others have mentioned, this is an _ATROCIOUS_ approach to your problem.  JavaScript is the wrong tool for this task.  You're inviting users to rip you off with this approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('#submit').click(function(){
  var input = $('#coupon').val();
  if(input === 'PROMO CODE'){
    $('#error').text('correct code!');
  } else if (input !== ''){
    $('#error').text('wrong code!');
  }
});
```

make sure you use `===` instead of `==` in JavaScript.